# Relying on /proc/[pid]/status for checking another process' identity

Tags: linux, security, ipc, pid, uid

Lately I came across the need for checking that a process with which my service interacts over IPC is privileged enough to perform certain transactions. The only information I have about the process is its pid and I am certain this pid is not a fake (the IPC is reliable enough to guarantee that). I need to check that the process has a specific uid or pid or is a member of a certain supplementary group and only then allow the transaction. To do that I  read the /proc/[pid]/status entry for the process, parse the Uid/Gid/Groups lines and act accordingly.

My question is whether this method of checking a process identity is reliable enough and if not where it might fail? I am concerned about situations in which a rogue process might be able to somehow fake my service's view of its /proc/[pid]/status or something like that. Am I being over paranoid here or is there a real concern to be considered?

NOTE: I came to choose this method as I was unable to find another way to get another process' identity in Linux. I would be happy if someone enlightens me on that too.

Answer (score 1):

An old but still good attack is to find a way to force the target process to exit, either by signal or through a bug of some kind. Then rapidly flood the PID space with new processes via fork until the attacker gets the right PID.

Checking /proc/pid/status each time does make this harder but it is still vaguely possible.

The successful attack would look something like:

Server 1234 Listening
    Client check 1234 has server UID -> True
Malicious kill Server 1234, start 32,000 new processes
    Client does IPC with Malicious 1234

Comment: Right, but the check is made for each transaction and the IPC mechanism guarantees that if the original process dies before the transaction is finished then the transaction will fail. In other words, hijacking the transaction is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with looking in /proc is that there are options (`hidepid` in `man procfs`) that mean you can't access the files (unless running as root), in addition to possible TOUTOC risks.

An alternative might be, if using Unix sockets (to switching to Unix sockets) is to use file system permissions to enforce access restrictions. (Assuming it is the server validating the clients)

If the client wants to validate the server, then a low TCP port might be sufficient (i.e. server running / started as root)
Or else checking ownership of a Unix socket.